# Replace end of string on many lines with values from array

Tags: linux, shell, text, sed, substitution

I have a file that contains:

```
asd x    
sometihng else    
asd x    
sometihng else    
asd x
```

and an array that contains `values=(3,4,5)`.
And now I want to replace the "x" on the first line in the file, with the value of the first element in the vector from a shell script. For all lines/elements. Such that I get

```
asd 3
sometihng else
asd 4
sometihng else
asd 5
```

How should I do this?

As of now, I tried using sed in a loop. Something like this:

```
values=(3 4 5)
lines=3
for currentLine in $(seq $lines)
do
     currentElement=$(expr "$currentLine" / "2")
     sed "$currentLine s/\(asd\)\(.*\)/\1 ${values[$currentElement]}/"
done
```

But for every run through the loop I get the entire original file with the interesting line edited, like so:

```
asd 3
sometihng else    
asd x    
sometihng else    
asd x

asd x
sometihng else    
asd 4    
sometihng else    
asd x

asd x
sometihng else    
asd x    
sometihng else    
asd 5
```

Thanks, Alex

Comment: Thanks! I'll add what i tried so you can see where I am at.

Comment: you'll need to use `sed -i` (see [portable use](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/3640/in-place-editing/12529/portable-use#t=201704200917386643334) for various versions) so as make the changes and write it back to file

Comment: First line of each section or first section?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be easier to use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN { a[1]=3; a[2]=4; a[3]=5; } /x/ { count++; sub(/x/, a[count]); } { print }'
```

If you insist on `sed`, however, you could try something like this:

```
{ echo "3 4 5"; cat some_file; } | \
    sed '1{h;d};/x/{G;s/x\(.*\)\n\([0-9]\).*/\1\2/;x;s/^[0-9] //;x}'
```